# Selenium send_keys to iframe, python

Tags: python, selenium

I have been having this major issue trying to `send_keys()` when in a iframe. A snippet of my html looks like this...

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" class="credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width" src="https://paymentcc.nike.com/services/cvv?id=5abb5718-573e-40a0-bf29-40ab3b9de9d2&amp;ctx=checkout&amp;language=undefined&amp;maskerEnabled=true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" title="Credit Card CVV Form"></iframe>

    <html content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets.commerce.nikecloud.com/ncss/glyphs/2.0/css/glyphs.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//assets.commerce.nikecloud.com/ncss/0.16/dotcom/desktop/css/ncss.en-us.min.css">
    
          <link href="/resources/css/all.min.css?v=1601382771491" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    
      <form id="creditCardForm" method="post">
    
        <div class="ncss-input-container mod-cvv-input error">
          <label class="ncss-label mr2-sm" for="cvNumber">Security Code</label>
          <input type="tel" id="cvNumber" tabindex="0" data-shortname="cvv" maxlength="4" placeholder="XXX" class="mod-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm" autocomplete="off" value="">
        </div>
    
          <input type="hidden" id="parentDomain" value="https://www.nike.com">
          <input type="hidden" id="enableIFrameBuster" value="false">
    
      </form>
    
            <script src="/resources/js/masker.js"></script>
            <script src="/resources/js/common.js"></script>
    
    
    </body></html>
```

I have been trying to switch my driver to iframe and select the xpath of my desired path for send_keys. My attempted code is...

```
#also tried with xpath
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width")
driver.switch_to_frame(element)
queryElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div/input")
queryElement.send_keys("123")
```

What should I do? Also I am trying to send_keys to `<input type="tel" id="cvNumber" tabindex="0" data-shortname="cvv" maxlength="4" placeholder="XXX" class="mod-input ncss-input pt2-sm pr4-sm pb2-sm pl4-sm" autocomplete="off" value="">`, don't know if this will help.

Also this is my error i receive.

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Comment: @arundeepchohan sorry, meant to post this.

Comment: Oh you have an issue with compound classes. Those are actually multiple classes. Use css selector. "frame.credit-card-iframe-cvv.mt1.u-full-width"

Comment: _I have been having this major issue_ It would help if you said what the issue is.  If you're getting an error, please post it.

Comment: Why are you using xpath to find the input element?  Finding by id is better, isn't it?

Comment: No id to find,his issue was using finding by class to find compound classes.

Comment: this is the error I get - NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".credit-card-iframe-cvv mt1 u-full-width"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)

Comment: @arundeepchohan, what do you mean add frame before first period?

Comment: "frame.credit-card-iframe-cvv.mt1.u-full-width"  this should work as a selector.

Comment: @arundeepchohan, i got ~ NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"frame.credit-card-iframe-cvv.mt1.u-full-width"}, any other ideas?

Comment: remove frame and then try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the **`iframe`**, you can use this selector `.credit-card-iframe-cvv.mt1.u-full-width`

And for the **`input`** you can locate by `id`, like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.credit-card-iframe-cvv.mt1.u-full-width')
driver.switch_to.frame(element)

queryElement = driver.find_element_by_id('cvNumber')
queryElement.send_keys('123')
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point is to extract the frame. You can do that by multiple ways like by xpath, css selector, tag name as well.

Snippet using xpath :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(//iframe[@sandbox='allow-scripts allow-same-origin'])
```

Snippet using CSS Selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".allow-scripts.allow-same-origin")
```

Snippet using Tag name:

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe')
```

Some any of the ways works to extract the frames and once it is found just switch the control from main page to frame by `switch.to` command.